# What is the exact class of the ".in" static variable in the System class?

Tags: java, class, static, system, inputstream

The Oracle Java specification pages that are online list the " .in " static variable in the System class as being of type InputStream.

However, the class InputStream is abstract. So, no instance of InputStream can exist.

Therefore, the developers must have subclassed InputStream to create the ".in" instance.

What is the exact type of the ".in" variable?

Thanks.

Comment: This is most likely implementation specific. Which JRE implementation are you referring to?

Comment: The 8th edition of Java SE.

Comment: Oracle's JRE to be exact.

Comment: Whatever the actual class is, don't count on it.  I wouldn't even be 100% sure it's the same when my input is in a Command Prompt console, redirected from a file, input into an IDE, etc., even if using the same JRE.  The whole point of making types abstract is that you work with them without having to know the exact class.  So if you cast it to a `(BufferedInputStream)` and try to work with that, you are breaking encapsulation and risking future program bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Even though [it's stored as an `InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), it is a `BufferedInputStream`:

```
System.out.println(System.in.getClass());
```

prints `class java.io.BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: Could you clarify that it's stored as an InputStream, even though the object itself is a BufferedInputStream, for clarity?

Comment: Thanks. Why do you suppose that they didn't list it as a BufferedInputStream?

Comment: I suspect they wanted to leave it implementation specific.

Comment: @newbiedoodle The static reference stored in the System class is of type InputStream (the abstract class), but the actual type is a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this

```
 System.out.println(System.in.getClass());
```

Which will print `java.io.BufferedInputStream`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code for Java's System class](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/System.java.html), you can see that it initially assigned to `null`:

```
/**
 * The "standard" input stream. This stream is already
 * open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream
 * corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by
 * the host environment or user.
 */
public final static InputStream in = null;
```

This says it is final... so how is it modified? Well, these fields on `System`  are special - see [JLS 17.5.4. Write-protected Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.4).

> Normally, a field that is final and static may not be modified.
>   However, System.in, System.out, and System.err are static final fields
>   that, for legacy reasons, must be allowed to be changed by the methods
>   System.setIn, System.setOut, and System.setErr. We refer to these
>   fields as being write-protected to distinguish them from ordinary
>   final fields.

Reading some of the documentation on the class you can see a few methods that initializes the class:

```
/**
 * Initialize the system class.  Called after thread initialization.
 */
private static void initializeSystemClass() {
    ....
    FileInputStream fdIn = new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in);
    FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
    FileOutputStream fdErr = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err);
    setIn0(new BufferedInputStream(fdIn));
    setOut0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));
    setErr0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdErr, 128), true));
```

Those `setIn0`, `setOut0`, and `setErr0` are all native methods that allow the field to be changed. You can see that in the normal case `System.in` is going to be a `BufferedInputStream`.

```
private static native void setIn0(InputStream in);
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
private static native void setErr0(PrintStream err);
```

In addition to that, `System` also offers a view methods that allow you to change where those streams go to. For example, for changing the "standard" input stream:

```
public static void setIn(InputStream in) {
    checkIO();
    setIn0(in);
}
```